# BufReader from a raw fd

Tags: rust

I'm using the [fdpass crate](https://crates.io/crates/fdpass) to send file descriptors from one process to another over an unix socket (I don't care about compatibility, unix only is fine).

Using mio I manage to listen for events on those file descriptors :

```
let fd = fdpass::recv_fd(&mut client, vec!(0u8)).unwrap();
let efd = EventedFd(&fd.into_raw_fd());

poll.register(&efd, Token(0), Ready::readable(), PollOpt::level()).unwrap();
```

That works perfectly fine, but I'd like to use a `BufReader` to read that file descriptor line by line. I've been trying to figure out a way to use `from_raw_fd()` on something that would implement `BufReader` unsucessfully. It seems to exist only for things like files or network streams. The only other thing is `Stdio` which does not implement Read, required for `BufRead`.

Any suggestions as to how I could get a `BufReader` from a raw fd without making mio unsafe to use?

The file descriptors by the way are not files (although they might be at some point) so I can't use `File::`, right now I'm just sending the client's stdin as a raw fd through fdpass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `FromRawFd` is only implemented for a [hand full of structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html#implementors). You need to know beforehand what kind of "file" you want to read or you risk undefined behavoir (because Rust assumes that a FD is a type that it isn't).

You can however implement your own struct which does nothing else than reading which is fine for all file descriptor. This can be done by a function call to `man (2) read`.

```
use libc;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::io::{Error, Read, Result};
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::os::unix::io::{FromRawFd, RawFd};

pub struct RawFdReader {
    fd: RawFd,
}

impl FromRawFd for RawFdReader {
    unsafe fn from_raw_fd(fd: RawFd) -> Self {
        Self { fd }
    }   
}

impl Read for RawFdReader {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {
        assert!(buf.len() <= isize::max_value() as usize);
        match unsafe { libc::read(self.fd, buf.as_mut_ptr() as _, buf.len()) } { 
            x if x < 0 => Err(Error::last_os_error()),
            x => Ok(x as usize),
        }
    }   
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut reader = unsafe { RawFdReader::from_raw_fd(0) };
    let mut buffer = vec![0; 10];
    let len = reader.read(&mut buffer)?;
    println!("{:?}", OsStr::from_bytes(&buffer[..len]));
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You can of course get rid of the `unsafe { RawFdReader::from_raw_fd(0) }` if you implement a static method (e.g. `new`) and pass a `RawFd` there because you know it's safe to construct.

Comment: Looks like this works fine indeed, thanks a lot ! I figured using read directly would work, but I imagined something like this would already exist