# How to read from custom file descriptors without using unsafe?

Tags: rust, file-descriptor

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858184/1135424), I learned that a file descriptor can be read using `unsafe`:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Read},
    os::unix::io::FromRawFd,
};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(3) };
    let mut input = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut input)?;

    println!("I read: {}", input);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
$ cat /tmp/output
Hello, world!
$ target/debug/example 3< /tmp/output
I read: Hello, world!
```

How can I achieve the same result without using `unsafe`?

I am currently creating a file descriptor like this (`zsh` shell):

```
function test_fd {
   if ! read -r line <&$1; then
       line="[Read on fd $1 failed]"
   fi

   echo $line

   # Remove the handler and close the fd
   zle -F $1
   exec {1}<&-
}

exec {FD}< <(/path/to/my/app)
zle -F $FD test_fd
```

I would like to replace the `test_fd` with something that could `read` or better if it could `read & close` the provided file descriptor so that I could end with something like:

```
function test_fd {
   /something/in/rust "$@"
}

exec {FD}< <(/path/to/my/app)
zle -F $FD test_fd
```

Comment: this unsafe look safe to do in your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BufReader from a raw fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812291/bufreader-from-a-raw-fd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. Your only avenue is to use `unsafe`.

As stated in [the documentation for `FromRawFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html#tymethod.from_raw_fd):

> This function is also unsafe as the primitives currently returned have the contract that they are the sole owner of the file descriptor they are wrapping. Usage of this function could accidentally allow violating this contract which can cause memory unsafety in code that relies on it being true.

You *may* be able to make use of the [`fcntl` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) to test if a given descriptor is valid, but I don't know the details about how these work in the presence of threading — it's possible that one thread checks for validity of the file descriptor and it's valid, another thread closes it, then the first attempts to use it. This is a straight-forward [Time-of-check to time-of-use issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

See also:

- [How to check if a given file descriptor stored in a variable is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12340695/155423)

Comment: How to deal with `unsafe` in these cases? is there a way to "trap/catch" if the file descriptor is not valid, etc?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the UB comes from, but I also don't understand enough about system calls to know what could go wrong when doing IO on a bad FD. How would a "safe" construct like the CPython interpreter handle something like this?

Comment: @turbulencetoo that's a good point; I have gotten error messages about invalid file descriptors, so there might be some checking at the OS level that prevents that. I'll see if I can make that text more accurate.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I've updated to use the docs exact wording, which uses "memory unsafety" as opposed to "undefined behavior"